# ModifiedDatetimeStart / end is not visible for metadata activity in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

ModifiedDatetimeStart / end is not visible for metadata activity in azure data factory for ftp dataset.
I have created ftp linked services and created dataset from it. But not able to see ModifiedDatetimeStart and
ModifiedDatetimeend in the meatadata activity .
Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't seen these in FTP - FileZilla, for instance, only shows LastModified. Have you tried adding LastModified to the GetMetadata field list?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood - are you referring to the "Filter by Last Modified Date"? Because this is definitely present in GetMetadata when the DataSet is SFTP.

Comment: We can add argument Last modified it's working. But the default parameter " filter by Last Modified Date" is not present by default for ftp

Comment: Interesting - I only use SFTP so I can't compare, but the option is definitely present in the GetMetadata activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modifiedDatetimeStart` and `modifiedDatetimeEnd`

These two properties are used to filter the child items when getting metadata from a folder. **It does not apply when getting metadata from a file.**

As per official documentation connectors to get `lastModified(file/folder)` is not supported.

[image]

Reference link : [Supported Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#supported-connectors)